# Can't call function defined within $(window).load from same event

Tags: jquery

So, I thought hoisting would take care of this. I've defined a function and am trying to call it from within the same event it was defined in. Specifically, some example code that's not working:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  doSomething()

  var doSomething = function(){
    alert('working')
  }

})
```

It's throwing me for a loop, since I'm invoking functions all through my code, but I just realized that they're all invoked from event handlers; none are running inline, except this one that I decided should run immediately.

I guess my question is, why isn't this function hoisted so I can call it in the same scope in which it was defined?

Answer (score 0):

Function definition hoisting only occurs for **function declarations**, not **function expressions**.

You need to change (window).ready as ready is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).ready(function(){

  doSomething()

  function doSomething(){
    alert('working')
  }

})
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use `$(window).ready(function(){` because that's deprecated, use `$(function(){`

Comment: Yeah, user was not getting because of function expression.Even if he change to $(function) user wont get it.

Comment: no. document.ready fires when the dom is ready. window.load fires after all resources have loaded. And changing to the code you recommended still doesn't solve my hoisting issue.

Answer (score 0):

change

> `$(window).load(function() {`

to

> `$(window).on('load',function() {`

because `$(window).load(...` is deprecated

then, try to declare `var doSomething = function(){ ...` first, then place `doSomething()` after that line

**corrected code:**

```
$(window).on('load',function() {

  var doSomething = function(){
    alert('working');
  }
  doSomething();

});
```

Comment: While that may be true, changing it doesn't fix the original issue; that my function is not hoisting.

Comment: @user1279629 it seems I see the problem now, try to declare `var doSomething = function(){ ...` first, then place `doSomething()` after that line

Comment: I mean, that technically works, but it's still not clear to me why the function isn't hositing. afaict, I should be able to call a function anywhere, not only after it's defined.